# Scala Futures: Non deterministic output

Tags: scala, future

I am new to Scala and I am practicing on the Futures lib by creating some retry schemes. Doing so I got the following piece of code:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Retries extends App {

  var retries = 0

  def resetRetries(): Unit = retries = 0

  def calc() = if (retries > 3) 10 else {
    retries += 1
    println(s"I am thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId} This is going to fail. Retry count $retries")
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This failed")
  }

  def fCalc(): Future[Int] = Future(calc())

  resetRetries()

  val ff = fCalc() // 0 - should fail
    .fallbackTo(fCalc()) // 1 - should fail
    .fallbackTo(fCalc()) // 2 - should fail
    .fallbackTo(fCalc()) // 3 - should fail
    .fallbackTo(fCalc()) // 4 - should be a success

  Await.ready(ff, 10.second)

  println(ff.isCompleted)
  println(ff.value)
}
```

Every time I run this code I am getting different results. Samples of the results i am getting are the following

Output 1

```
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 14 This is going to fail. Retry count 3
I am thread 13 This is going to fail. Retry count 2
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 4
true
Some(Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This failed))
```

Output 2

```
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 2
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 13 This is going to fail. Retry count 3
I am thread 14 This is going to fail. Retry count 4
true
Some(Success(10))
```

Ouput 3

```
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 2
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 3
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 4
true
Some(Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This failed))
```

It's not always the case that the results would be alternating between success and failure. There might be more than a couple failed runs until a successful one appears.

To my understanding, there should be only 4 logs of the "I am thread x This is going to fail. Retry count x" and these should be the following:

```
I am thread a This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread b This is going to fail. Retry count 2
I am thread c This is going to fail. Retry count 3
I am thread d This is going to fail. Retry count 4
```

Not necessarily in this order - since I do not know how the Scala threading model works exactly - but you get my point. Nevertheless, I am getting this nondeterministic output I cannot come to grips with.So...
my question is: Where does this non deterministic output come from?

I would like to mention that the following retry mechanism yields consistently the same results:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Retries extends App {

  var retries = 0

  def resetRetries(): Unit = retries = 0

  def calc() = if (retries > 3) 10 else {
    retries += 1
    println(s"I am thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId} This is going to fail. Retry count $retries")
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This failed")
  }

  def retry[T](op: => T)(retries: Int): Future[T] = Future(op) recoverWith { case _ if retries > 0 => retry(op)(retries - 1) }

  resetRetries()
  val retriableFuture: Future[Future[Int]] = retry(calc())(5)
  Await.ready(retriableFuture, 10 second)

  println(retriableFuture.isCompleted)
  println(retriableFuture.value)
}
```

Output

```
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 2
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 3
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 4
true
Some(Success(10))
```

While if I reduce the number of retries (`retry(calc())(3)`), the result is a failed future as expected

```
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 1
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 2
I am thread 11 This is going to fail. Retry count 3
I am thread 12 This is going to fail. Retry count 4
true
Some(Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This failed))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although technically @Tim is correct I don't think he really answers this question.

I believe the real source of your confusion is your misunderstanding of what the constructions:

```
f.fallbackTo(Future(calc()))
```

does. And how it is different from

```
f.recoverWith({ case _ => Future(calc())})
```

There are two important distinctions:

1. In the `fallbackTo` case the `Future(calc())` is created immediately and thus (almost) immediately starts execution of the `calc()`. Thus the original future and the fallback future are run concurrently. In the case of the `recoverWith` the fallback future is created only after the failure of the original future. This difference affects the logging order. Also this means that the access to the `var retries` is concurrent and thus you might see the case when all threads actually fail because some updates to `retries` are lost.
2. Another tricky point is that `fallbackTo` is [documented](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html) as (highlighting is mine)

> Creates a new future which holds the result of this future if it was completed successfully, or, if not, the result of the that future if that is completed successfully. **If both futures are failed**, the **resulting future** holds the throwable object of **the first future.**

This difference does not really affect your example because the exception you throw in all failed attempts is the same but it might have affected the result if they were different. For example if you modify your code to:

```
  def calc(attempt: Int) = if (retries > 3) 10 else {
    retries += 1
    println(s"I am thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId} This is going to fail. Retry count $retries")
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"This failed $attempt")
  }

  def fCalc(attempt: Int): Future[Int] = Future(calc(attempt))

  val ff = fCalc(1) // 0 - should fail
      .fallbackTo(fCalc(2)) // 1 - should fail
      .fallbackTo(fCalc(3)) // 2 - should fail
      .fallbackTo(fCalc(4)) // 3 - should fail
      .fallbackTo(fCalc(5)) // 4 - should be a success
```

then you should get either of those two results

```
Some(Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This failed 1))
Some(Success(10))
```

and never any other "failed" value.

Note that here I explicitly pass the `attempt` to not hit the race condition on `retries`.

---

**Answer to more comments** (Jan 28)

The reason I explicitly pass `attempt` in my previous example is that it is the simplest way to ensure that the `IllegalArgumentException` created by the logically first `calc` will get `1` as its value under all (even not very realistic) thread schedules.

If you just interested in having all logs to have different values there is a much easier way: use a local variable!

```
  def calc() = {
    val retries = atomicRetries.getAndIncrement()
    if (retries > 3) 10 
    else {
      println(s"I am thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId} This is going to fail. Retry count $retries")
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"This failed $retries")
    }
  }
```

In this way you avoid classical [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem.

Comment: Introducing an AtomicInteger did not solve the problem of the logging but it did tackle the problem of the successful output which according to what you're saying should not have been tackled since: "for your example to return `Some(Success(10))` the last thread should win the race against all the other threads and it is started after them all"

Comment: @Niko, sorry I was wrong. I don't know what I was thinking about at that time. That claim is obviously wrong.  A successful last future will result in a successful total result irrespective of timing. I still find this difference between `fallbackTo` and `recoverWith` interesting but it is irrelevant in this question. I'll fix my answer soon.

Comment: As for the logging I'm not sure what exactly you see as a problem. You have a simple choice of when to start the "fallback" futures: concurrently with the main one or sequentially. In any real "retry" scenario that I can think of, you want them to be sequential or else it is not a retry. `fallbackTo` does not ensure this sequential order, on the contrary it runs the `Future`s concurrently and thus the logging happens concurrently. You still can ensure sequential order of logging by using some additional synchronization but this is a weird way to achieve a simple thing doable with `recoverWith`

Comment: @Tim , @SergGr My concern has nothing to do with the _order_ of the logging. The outputs are:
A
(...) Retry count 2
(...) Retry count 2
(...) Retry count 3
(...) Retry count 4
B
(...) Retry count 2
(...) Retry count 1
(...) Retry count 3
(...) Retry count 4

**2** is printed twice in the first case and I am using an `AtomicInteger` for the **times** var. This is what I am not getting. Even though the threads start simultaneously (in the `fallbackTo` case), to my understanding this should not happen if `times` is an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Your point regarding the ordering of the log is clear and I am not worried about this. Using the `attempt` count as a parameter in `fCalc` will indeed eradicate any race condition in the logging part. Don't know though if by becoming more intuitive it's becoming less of a retry scheme. Thanks a lot for the time you put into this :)

Comment: @Niko You do not show how you introduced the `AtomicInteger`, but if it is anything like `if (retries.getAndIncrement() > 3) 10 else { println(s"... $retries"); ... }` then of course the value you print may not be the same value you increment `retries` to - the other threads may have incremented it in the meantime.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski The implementation is the following: `def calc() = if (time.get() > 3) 10 else { time.getAndIncrement(); println(s"I am thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId} This is going to fail. Retry count ${time.get()}"); throw new IllegalStateException(("not yet")); }`. But I see your point. The print statement can still be affected by a `getAndIncrement` from another thread... I suppose there should be a method level synchronisation to fix this.

Comment: @Niko, you seem to hit the classical [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem. The simplest way to avoid it in this case is to use a local variable. See my updated answre.

Comment: @SergGr I will mark your response as the answer to the question. It includes more a couple of insights and your final addition is for sure one way to tackle the logging issue. I tested it - although the order is not respected, but I do not care about that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Niko, I believe the main point of my answer might get lost in those discussion, and the main point is that if you use `fallbackTo` the logic you get can't really be called "retry" because all the attempts are run concurrently. For "retry" you really need to use `recoverWith` that runs next attempt only when the previous has failed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Scala problem but a more general multi-threading problem with the value `retries`. You have multiple threads reading and writing this value without any synchronisation, so you can't predict when each thread will run or what value it will see.

It looks like the specific problem is that you are testing `retries` and then updating it later. It is possible that all four threads test the value before any of them updates it. In this case they would all see `0` and throw an error.

The solution is to turn `retries` into an `AtomicInteger` and use `getAndIncrement`. This will atomically retrieve the value and increment it, so each thread will see the appropriate value.

---

**Update following comments**: The other answer has explained why it is that multiple threads are being started at the same time so I won't repeat it here. With multiple threads running in parallel the order of the logging is always going to be non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually worked for me:

(The following code for `calc()` method adequately tackles the issues regarding logging duplication and futures' non deterministic results)

```
var time = 0
  var resetTries = time = 0

  def calc() = this.synchronized {
    if (time > 3) 10 else {
      time += 1
      println(s"I am thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId} This is going to fail. Retry count $time") // For debugging purposes
      throw new IllegalStateException(("not yet"))
    }
  }
```

No `AtomicInteger` required - makes things even more complicated in my opinion. A `synchronised` wrapper is what is needed.

I must highlight the fact that this is just for demonstration purposes and using such a design in a production code might not be the best idea (blocking calls to `calc` method). One should use the `recoverWith` implementation instead.

Thanks to @SergGr , @Tim and @MichalPolitowksi for their help